# Set debounced search in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, polaris

I'm new in ReactJS. But used to with VueJS. Previously, I was developing the projects in VueJS. But in ReactJS, I'm facing difficulty in setting pagination where I want something like this.

> Whenever user changes search value, it should reset the page number to
> 1 and make API call to fetch results.

This is making trouble for me. Can anyone help here please?

The problem is if I change search value for multiple times without changing page, it's not making API call again because page value is not changed. Here is my code.

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState, useMemo, useRef} from 'react';
import {useHistory, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import _ from 'lodash';
const queryString = require('query-string');
import {Page, Card, DataTable, Filters, Link, Stack, Pagination, Spinner} from '@shopify/polaris';

function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}

export default function App() {

    const params = queryString.parse(location.search);

    const [from, setFrom] = useState(0);
    const [to, setTo] = useState(0);
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [hasPrevious, setHasPrevious] = useState(false);
    const [hasNext, setHasNext] = useState(false);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(params.page ? parseInt(params.page) : 1);
    const [queryValue, setQueryValue] = useState(params.search ? params.search : null);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const queryParams = useMemo(() => {
        let queryParamsObject = {};
        if (page > 1) queryParamsObject.page = page;
        if (queryValue) queryParamsObject.search = queryValue;
        return queryParamsObject;
    }, [page, queryValue]);

    const prevPage = usePrevious(page);
    const prevQueryValue = usePrevious(queryValue);

    const handleFiltersQueryChange = useCallback((value) => setQueryValue(value), []);
    const handleQueryValueRemove = useCallback((value) => setQueryValue(null),[]);
    const handleFiltersClearAll = useCallback(() => handleQueryValueRemove(), [handleQueryValueRemove]);

    const rows = useMemo(() => {
        return items.map(item => {
            return [
                <Link removeUnderline url={`/items/${item.id}`}>{item.title}</Link>,
                item.email
            ];
        });
    }, [items]);

    const fetchItems = useCallback((params) => {

        setLoading(true);
        window.axios.get(`/items`, {params}).then((response) => {

            setItems(response.data.data);
            setFrom(response.data.from);
            setTo(response.data.to);
            setTotal(response.data.total);
            setHasPrevious(Boolean(response.data.prev_page_url));
            setHasNext(Boolean(response.data.next_page_url));
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    
    const debouncedSearch = useCallback(_.debounce((params) => {
        if (params.page === page) {
            history.push({pathname: '/items', search: queryString.stringify(params)});
            fetchItems(params);
        } else {
            setPage(1);
        }
    }, 1000), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof prevQueryValue !== "undefined" && prevQueryValue !== queryValue) {
            debouncedSearch(queryParams);
        } else {
            history.push({pathname: '/items', search: queryString.stringify(queryParams)});
            fetchItems(queryParams);
        }
    }, [page, queryValue]);

    return (
        <Filters
            queryValue={queryValue}
            filters={[]}
            onQueryChange={handleFiltersQueryChange}
            onQueryClear={handleQueryValueRemove}
            onClearAll={handleFiltersClearAll}
            queryPlaceholder="Filter items"
        />
        <DataTable
            columnContentTypes={[
                'text',
                'text',
            ]}
            headings={[
                'Col1',
                'Col2',
            ]}
            rows={rows}
            footerContent={`Showing ${from} to ${to} of ${total} results`}
        />
        {hasPrevious || hasNext ? <div className="pagination"><Stack distribution="center"><Pagination hasPrevious={hasPrevious} hasNext={hasNext} onPrevious={() => setPage(parseInt(page) - 1)} onNext={() => setPage(parseInt(page) + 1)} /></Stack></div> : null}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake. It just required to add one more condition in if condition in debouncedSearch function.

Here is the new function

```
     const debouncedSearch = useCallback(_.debounce((params) => {
        if ((params.page && params.page === page) || (!params.page && page === 1)) {
            history.push({pathname: '/items', search: queryString.stringify(params)});
            fetchItems(params);
        } else {
            setPage(1);
        }
    }, 1000), []);
```

But still, I don't think that this is the proper standard way. So, if anyone knows the proper way, it will be appreciated.